# band together chars to string for printing in hebrew Encoding

Tags: c#, printing

i need to print hebrew Characters to BT printer through Windows-Mobile.

if i print like this:

```
 line += string.Concat((char)143, (char)144, (char)147, (char)128);
```

its print excellent.  `אבג`

so, i try to build procc that take the word and make it like

`string.Concat((char)143.....`  but Without success.

i try this:

```
char[] RES;

public char []  HEB(string N)
{
    RES = new char[100];
    int j = 0;
    string TAV;

    for (int i = 0; i < N.Length; i++)
    {
        TAV = N[i].ToString().Trim();
        switch (TAV)
        {
            case "א": RES[j] += (char)143;
                break;
            case "ב": RES[j] += (char)144;
                break;
            case "ג": RES[j] += (char)145;
                break;
            case "ד": RES[j] += (char)146;
                break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return RES;
}
```

and this for the print:    `line += HEB("אבג").ToString();`

but its print this: `System.Char[]`

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are getting that cause in your code line `line += HEB("אבג").ToString();` `HEB("אבג")` returns a `char[]` (character array) on which you are calling `ToString()`. You should rather loop through the returned array and then display each item instead. See your method signature (as below) as it returns an char array.

```
    public char []  HEB(string N)
    {
```

You should rather do like

```
foreach(char c in HEB("אבג"))
{
  line += c.ToString();
}
```